# jQuery read JSON one object at a time

Tags: jquery, json, loading

I have a potentially extensive list of JSON list of objects. I'd like to load each item individually rather than all of them in one large chunk and display a loading icon as each item is being downloaded. Can this be done with jQuery .get requests with just one JSON file?

Comment: Maybe try checking the progress, see http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has nothing built in to do this.

You *could* request some data using XMLHttpRequest and then parse the partial data when the `progress` event fired and the `readyState` was at least 3 (loading) rather then waiting for 4 (done).

Since this would involve having incomplete, and therefore invalid, JSON, you would have to implement a custom parser to do this. You would need a strategy for dealing with partial pieces of data (such as half of an object or string).

You would also have to either count characters or reparse the entire set of data each time the `readyStateChange` event fired.

It is probably far more trouble then is worth.

You'd likely be better off altering the server side logic to allow for paging of the data.